# Gatsby: TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined

Tags: gatsby

I am fairly new to gatsby. ** **I am using gatsby version:2.18.4** **

I just created a new project using gatsby cli. Then, created some fresh pages.

Now, I am getting this error. Not sure, where I am going wrong.[image: see attached image]

[image: this is my project structure]

Comment: This is because `pageResources`  is undefined. Thus extracting a property, ``page`` from an undefined object, `pageResources` leads to  this error, `Cannot read property "page" of undefined`.

Comment: Can you log `locationAndPageResources` to see if it has a property called `pageResources`  ?

Comment: @CCC log it from which `component/page`? PS: I have done any changes with `pageResources`. Just created some new pages.

Comment: As it is shown in the first picture you posted, it is from `E:/gatsby-site/.cache/root.js:74`

Comment: @CCC .cache/ is an auto-generated folder by the gatsby cli. Actual code is in the `src` folder.

Comment: if it is an auto-generated folder, then it is using your code,  edit the question by adding your code, not auto-generated code.

Comment: @CCC The screenshot I have shared is what I see in my localhost. I sounds like you are aware of gatsby in general. no problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: Your page names have to be lowercased

Comment: @LekoArts updated them to lowercase. but, still the same error.